# How to fire the "iron-localstorage-load" event?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'd like to load some data into my view. For now I am using the [`iron-localstorage`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-localstorage) element.

Because I want to use animations, I have to time the playing of the animation after the data from the `iron-localstorage` element has loaded.

According to the docs there is `iron-localstorage-load` Event that is:

> Fired when value loads from localStorage.

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-localstorage

But for some reason the event does not fire.

Here is what I use:

```
<iron-localstorage 
    name="library-storage" 
    value="{{value}}" 
    on-iron-localstorage-load-empty="initializeDefaultCards" 
    on-iron-localstorage-load="handleLocalstorageLoadEvent">
</iron-localstorage>
```

And here the method that should handle the load event:

```
handleLocalstorageLoadEvent: function() {
    alert('Localstorage Loaded');
},
```

Here is the Plnkr: (I used also an iron-ajax element, to show that event from iron-ajax are fired, compared to the event from `iron-localstorage`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/idN3fnNp8lbhR0jjx5Rs?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't set any value into `value` so it never saves to localstorage. Because of this, you can never load from localstorage.

In your plunkr, if you change to `{{cards}}` you'd start to receive that event.

Comment: Actually I didn't need to set any value, since my demo is working right now. Not sure why suddenly the event is fired.